# What does the denominator in the Adjusted Rand Index mean?

Tags: clustering

According to [Scikit's documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#mathematical-formulation), the Adjusted Rand Index (ARI) can be defined as:

$$\mathrm{ARI} = \frac{\mathrm{RI} - \mathbb{E}[\mathrm{RI}]}{\max(\mathrm{RI})-\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{RI}]}$$

I don't understand what the $\max(\mathrm{RI})$ refers to. The formula to calculate it can be found [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index#Definition_2) for example, but I want to know intuitively why that value appears there instead of the total number of pairs as in the denominator of the $\mathrm{RI}$ (the not-adjusted version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum possible RI, of a perfect result.

This is the usual adjustment for chance scaling, that maps the best possible result to 1, a random result to 0, and anything worse than random to less than 0.

Comment: But isn't the maximum possible RI always $1$, by definition? In this case, why is the denominator $\max(\mathrm{RI})  - \mathbb{E}[\mathrm{RI}]$ instead of $1  - \mathbb{E}[\mathrm{RI}]$?

Comment: It should be 1 - until you cancel out the common terms. There is nothing wrong with writing max RI even if it is 1, if you want to emphasize that you *need* the maximum (but don't care if it is 1 for RI). The same equation can also be used, e.g., with MI then.

Comment: I may sound stupid here, but what does a perfect result mean? If I'm comparing A and B, does the denominator denote the RI score if A looks exactly like B and vice versa? In that case, if I compare A and C, wouldn't the value be the same then (well this is not the case when i calculate it by hand).